# multiple sum involving dependent variables in sympy

Tags: sum, sympy

In sympy

```
summation(120*factorial(2*x1)*factorial(2*x2)*factorial(2*x3)*factorial(-2*x1 - 2*x2 - 2*x3 + 10)/(factorial(x1)*factorial(x2)*factorial(x3)*factorial(-x1 - x2 - x3 + 5)),(x3,1,4-x1-x2),(x2,1,3-x1),(x1,1,2))
```

gives

```
Sum(Piecewise((120*(2*factorial(2*x1)*factorial(2*x2)*factorial(-2*x1 - 2*x2 + 8)*hyper((1, 3/2), (x1 + x2 - 7/2,), exp_polar(I*pi))/factorial(-x1 - x2 + 4) - factorial(2*x1)*factorial(2*x2)*factorial(-2*x1 - 2*x2 + 10)*hyper((1, -x1 - x2 + 11/2), (1/2,), exp_polar(I*pi))/factorial(-x1 - x2 + 5))/(factorial(x1)*factorial(x2)), Or(-re(x1) - re(x2) + 6 < 0, And(-re(x1) - re(x2) + 6 < 1, -re(x1) - re(x2) + 6 >= 0))), (120*Sum(factorial(2*x1)*factorial(2*x2)*factorial(2*x3)*factorial(-2*x1 - 2*x2 - 2*x3 + 10)/(factorial(x3)*factorial(-x1 - x2 - x3 + 5)), (x3, 1, -x1 - x2 + 4))/(factorial(x1)*factorial(x2)), True)), (x2, 1, -x1 + 3), (x1, 1, 2))
```

How could I evaluate this sum? Could I make appropriate assumptions about x1 and x2 to simplify the expression? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: Regarding assumptions, you know that your variables are positive and integers (because they are summation indices), so you can use `x1, x2, x3, x4 = symbols('x1:5', positive=True, integer=True)`. All that does in this case is remove the `re`s, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SymPy is missing a very important thing here, which is that your outer sum is just between `x1 = 1` and `x1 = 2`.  Performing that simplification makes the summations simple enough that SymPy can do them

```
In [75]: e = 120*factorial(2*x1)*factorial(2*x2)*factorial(2*x3)*factorial(-2*x1 - 2*x2 - 2*x3 + 10)/(factorial(x1)*factorial(x2)*factorial(x3)*factorial(-x1 - x2 - x3 + 5))

In [76]: e2 = Sum(e, (x3,1,4-x1-x2),(x2,1,3-x1)).subs(x1, 1) + Sum(e, (x3,1,4-x1-x2),(x2,1,3-x1)).subs(x1, 2)

In [77]: e2.doit()
Out[77]: 46080
```